# Configure network stack to consume data from TAP device, so that application can operate as if the data was intended to it

Tags: linux-networking, nftables, tap

I have two devices communicating, A and B over udp.

In between there is a tap device, where C is connected. In order for C to be able to receive the traffic it needs to set the same ip and mac address as A. **(1) This works showing the data intended for A** (which is sent from B). However when i also add B (to see the incoming traffic from A) everything stops working.

I assume this is due to conflict of dual pairs of ip configured. I guess that internal routing gets prioritised and. So **(1)** stops working because the B address also resides on the same machine which isn't producing any traffic.

What can i do about this?

Goal is to be able to get `nc -v -u -l <IP_from_A_or_B> 2000 | hd`

Surely this scenario isn't unusual when tapping data? Instead of writing promiscuous i would love to be able to solve this with configuration. With or without additional nodes in the network.

Comment: This is what promiscuous mode is for. Why do you not want to use that?

Comment: Well i like my application to consume traffic as if it was intended to it (in this case it's about decoding data), so I would like to avoid an additional binary which would operate in promiscuous mode.